# useEffect being called twice in Nextjs Typescript app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, frontend

I have a simple useEffect function setup with the brackets like so:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('hello')
    getTransactions()
  }, [])
```

However when I run my app, it prints two hellos in the console. Any idea why?

Even if I add something like this, two hellos print still.

```
  const [useEffectCalled, setUseEffectCalled] = useState<Boolean>(false)

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('hello')
    if (!useEffectCalled) {
      getTransactions()
    }
    setUseEffectCalled(true)
  }, [])
```

Comment: Maybe something in `getTransactions` is causing a complete re-loading (or remounting) of the component, triggering it once again? Comment it out and see if it still triggers twice, try to locate where the problem is exactly.

Comment: @cSharp commented out `getTransactions` just including the `console.log` in useEffect and same thing, logged two hellos...strangest thing

Comment: Is your app using Strict Mode?

Comment: Even if it is in strict mode, useEffect with no dependency, will only run once unless your component remounts.

Comment: For a in depth answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72238175/react-18-useeffect-is-getting-called-two-times-on-mount.

Answer (score 57):

Thanks to Joel Hager I was able to get it working by editing by `next.config.js`
to

```
const nextConfig = {
  reactStrictMode: false,
};
```

and restarting my app.

Comment: I also got duplicated execution of useEffect and disabling it also worked for me, but I hate not knowing why. ReactStrictMode is supposed to help highlighting potential problems, not create them. Does anyone understand why is this happening? I am using next v12.1.6 + react v18.1.0

Comment: You shouldn't forget to restart your server as well. `next.config.js` is applied on server startup.

Comment: You shouldn't be systematically deactivating `StrictMode`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72238175/react-18-useeffect-is-getting-called-two-times-on-mount

Comment: still happening with next v13, internet is saying this is a react issue so i'm not sure what is going on and the solution for it. disabling strict mode sounds wrong.

Comment: @Ander maybe you use rewrite https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72302343/next-js-app-is-rendered-twice-with-rewrites

Comment: Nice feature...