# NEXT JS - App is rendered twice with rewrites

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I'm developing a NEXT JS project and can't find a solution for a twice rendering app!

**Problem**

After adding **rewrites** to `next.config.js`, App is rendered twice. If remove, rendred once.

`next.config.js`

```
async rewrites() {
  return [
    {
      source: '/about',
      destination: '/',
    },
  ]
},
```

`_app.js`

```
function MyApp() {
  console.log('App render');

  return (<></>);
}

export default MyApp
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

this should be expected behavior-- as rewrites cause double renders in nextjs

Comment: Hmm... Very strange 

Comment: @ucoder92

https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/33028#issuecomment-1006179699

Comment: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/33028

Comment: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/34277

Comment: Maintainer of repo says in your links: 
"This is actually expected when you have a rewrites in your config and is vaguely hinted at in the docs here: https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/automatic-static-optimization"

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).